# Merge/combine fields from two database tables

Tags: mysql, database, merge

I have two tables in my database which I want to join some matching results from.

```
ps_product (column names): id_product | reference | price | wholesale_price
ps_stock (column names): id_product | quantity
```

I would like to combine these two tables to get:

```
Table: id_product | reference | quantity | price | wholesale_price
```

Both tables have matching id_product values and should be matched, so quantity fits the right reference and so forth. Saved to a csv file if possible.

Running mysql on Debian.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `inner join` as

```
select 
p.id_product,
p.reference,
s.quantity,
p.price,
p.wholesale_price
from ps_product p
join ps_stock s on s.id_product = p.id_product
```